# C# Selenium Can't Locate to any Element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Why C# + Selenium can't locate to any element from this URL only

> 

I want to try to filling data to textbox programmatically using c# + selenium.
I had tried for some sites and it worked, but only that site it doesn't work. This is my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.testDriver();

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Done!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void testDriver()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://atrium.xsis.co.id/#!/");

        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));  //Unable to locate element
        //IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));  //Unable to locate element
        //IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));  //Unable to locate element
        //IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));  //Unable to locate element
        //IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='password']"));  //Unable to locate element
        //IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='email']"));  //Unable to locate element
        //IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='password']"));  //Unable to locate element
        //IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='email']"));  //Unable to locate element

        login.SendKeys("MyName");
        login.Submit();

        //------------------------------Some sites, i have tried
        /*  --It Worked
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://accounts.google.com/");
        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Name("identifier"));
        login.SendKeys("MyName");
        login.Submit();
        */

        /*  --It Worked
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://web.facebook.com/");
        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
        login.SendKeys("MyName");
        login.Submit();
        */

        /*  --It Worked
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://stackoverflow.com/");
        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Name("display-name"));
        login.SendKeys("MyName");
        login.Submit();
        */

        /*  --It Worked
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://github.com/login?");
        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Name("login"));
        login.SendKeys("MyName");
        login.Submit();
        */
    }
}
```

I think that is simple code, just locate specific element. Or use other method if the web using IFrame, but there is no frame.
I am using vs 2013 community edition, WebDriver.dll version 3.4.0.0, RunTime version v4.0.30319., and Firefox 54.0.1 (32-bit).

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Okay sir, i edited. Please read and correct me if i am wrong @JeffC

Comment: That's much better. Thanks for the edit and listing a lot of different tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good... something simple like your first attempt, `By.Id("email")`, should have worked. When it doesn't you want to look first to see if the desired element is in an `IFRAME`. In this case, it isn't.

The next thing you should try is an explicit wait, `WebDriverWait`.

```
IWebElement email = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("email")));
email.SendKeys("MyName");
email.Submit();
```

The `wait.Until()` returns the element waited for so you can capture that by assigning the return to a variable and then using it, as I did above.

Comment: Sir, i wanna ask again. Why when i instantiate new FirefoxDriver, it always open new window? How to using existing browser window? @JeffC

Comment: When i just type IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); it automatically open new window

Comment: So when i opened facebook, facebook detects  that it is new browser, and need phone verification

Comment: These are all new questions that should be asked in a different question. Having said that... these have been asked before. Instantianting the driver always launches a new browser. You cannot attach a process to an existing browser.

Answer (score 1):

There's something which is kind of cool and annoying at sometime in Selenium, it literally try to work exactly as if the user where using the browser. Hence you gotta be sure that the element exposed on your screen and the user can click on it, otherwise you must scrool until it.

Another important thing is the bootstrap, which sometimes change the visibility of its elements and replace to others.

- Scrool to elements on page's bottom.
- Guarantee the element is literally visible.
- Check whether there's something over the element.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet and I'd prefer that this be a comment, but here goes anyway.

I tried browsing to the site you reference and can't get there. Not sure if it's live or not or just blocked by my company's firewall. I really wanted to look at the code for the site because I've seen issues like this before. Typically when I've seen this it's either a locater issue or an iframe issue. If you could post the html from the site that would help diagnose your issue. Oh, and the code you have written looks correct, but that doesn't help if Selenium is looking in the wrong frame.

So, here's what I would try.

First, I'd use FireFox's developer version and inspect the element. Make sure it's not inside of a frame that you haven't noticed.

Second, I'd try to locate by CSSSelector. I know that it should work by Id or XPath, but sometimes it doesn't and I don't know why. However, I have had luck with locating by CSSSelector when the others fail. You can copy the CSS Selector directly out of the inspection window in FireFox's developer version.

Third, if none of that works, I'd pass a SwitchTo the Default Content Frame, just in case the entire page is in a frame that is buried inside a div that you're missing. The code for that is:

```
 driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Finally, the last thing I would try is adding some explicit waits just in case there is an element loading after you are trying to access it. Unfortunately this happens more than I'd like.

This would be my final, kitchen sink, approach.

```
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
 driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
 By emailLocator = By.CSSSelector("insert CSS Selector Here");
 IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(emailLocator);
 email.SendKeys("email address");
```

If that still doesn't work, please post the html for the page you're trying to access and we'll see if we can figure out why it's failing to locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Xpath? 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']"))`

I find that sometimes Selenium is finicky and you need to try other approaches to find elements.

Comment: thank for your comment. I have just tried it, and still gave me same error message "unable to locate element".    IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='email']"));